# How to display a 2D image in a GvrView on Android?

Tags: java, android, image, opengl-es, google-vr

I'm currently working on an **Android** app to **display 3D pictures using VR**. Every 3D picture consists of **two images** taken from slightly different perspectives: one for the right eye, and one for the left eye. Now I need to display them side-by-side with **distortion correction** applied. While the side-by-side part should be pretty easy to implement, the distortion correction is a different matter.

The obvious library to look into for VR distortion correction was the [Google VR SDK](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/reference_overview). However, I can't really find the functionality I need. Apparently there are two ways to display 3D content in the Google VR SDK:

- Either you use the **VR Panorama View**, which may seem like the obvious solution because it was created to display 3D images. However, it unfortunately expects a 360 degrees panorama. It therefore applies the given texture to a 360 degree photosphere so that you can only see a tiny part of the image. Also, the merging points above, below and behind look very weird.
- The other option which I am now looking at is to use a **GvrView** in a GvrActivity. The GvrView uses a GvrView.StereoRenderer to display its content. This seems very similar to the normal GLSurfaceView which enables you to display OpenGL content using a GLSurfaceView.Renderer. But while I managed to set a **background image** in a GLSurfaceView using setBackgroundResource(), the background in a GvrView remains black if I call the same method.

Now my question is: Is there any way to **display a 2D picture in a GvrView** (with or without GvrView.StereoRenderer)?

Or if that is not the case: Would the best way be to draw the image onto a square and make it take up the whole field of view? Or should I do the distortion by myself in the first place? If so, do you know a good way to do this?

If you have any ideas, please answer. Thank you very much in advance!

Skoebuga

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem with stereoscopic videos and i found the solution a few days ago.

So quick answer to your question : Yes, you can display a stereoscopic image or video with the GvrView and render part of the image/video for each eye.

A GvrView.Renderer or GvrView.StereoRenderer is a mandatory step because if you do not give a renderer to your GvrView, you will have a NullPointerException.

Here's a quick and dirty example based on Matthew Welling's work (it is an updated-cut,corrected version that display a stereoscopic left/right video).

https://github.com/Zanfas/Cardboard_VideoPlayer

So first bad news : you will have to learn Open GL ES and 3D scene management. The Google VR SDK doesn't do any rendering work (except if you use VrPanoWidget or VrVideoView but they only do 360° rendering and it sucks if you just want to display videos or images that are not meant to be displayed in 360°).

The idea is to draw the video or the image in a SurfaceTexture, display this texture (or the left part or the right part depending on the eye you are rendering for) in a virtual screen put somewhere in a 3D scene. You do the rendering of the 3D scene (with the camera that looks at this virtual screen) and then, the Google VR SDK post process this rendering to apply distorsion.

The trick to have a good and immersive rendering is to make that virtual screen filling all the field of view of the user (you have to see only the full screen. No more, no less). In order to achieve that, with this example, you just have to play with the size of the virtual screen and the distance you put that screen away from the camera.

Regards